# Restoring Data from image.dd

Tags: hard-drive, backup, data-recovery, restore, dd

A few days ago I was in a middle of copying or cutting folders and data to my external hard drive and it was corrupted.

I have tried to locate the lost information on Test Disk but I have now lost it because it has already been over written. The file is 0. 0. copy and completed.

I have now only have the image.dd file. How can I restore this to it's normal folders and files? Many thanks.

Comment: What kind of files are on the hard disk? (meaning, is directory structure absolutely critical?)

Comment: What does `file image.dd` show? [Edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 1):

If directory structure isn't really serious (or you can work through the difficulties that it creates) I'd recommend photorec.  I believe it comes along with testdisk, so you can simply run it with:

```
photorec myfile.dd
```

From thereon out the procedure is relatively clear, but post back if you have issues.  It will make folders with the files sorted basically totally randomly, so if directory structure is important... maybe not the best, unless you have a good amount of time to go sorting through.  Otherwise, I've had successes numerous times with it.

Comment: If I use photorec, it will disorganize my  files and lose the names of the files. It be hard to organise them again..

Comment: The problem with this.... it will lose the names of the files and it will lose the folders.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I asked.  Even if it doesn't work for you, it might be worth running it just to verify that you *can get* the files off your dd.